# Adaptive card not displaying on mobile clients

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow, adaptive-cards

I'm sending custom adaptive card from flow..

It is working on web and mobile clients for my Dev environment.. The same thing fails in my client's tenant for his android and iOS .. His web displays adaptive card right.. Any ideas?

I've got approval for the originator

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the type of card to "**AdaptiveCard**" instead of "**AdaptiveCards**".

For example:

```
{ 
    "fallbackText":"Adaptive card version not supported",
    "type":"AdaptiveCard",
    "body":[ 
       { 
          "text":"Here is an adaptive card with a link to a task module",
          "type":"TextBlock"
       },
       { 
          "type":"Image",
          "url":"http://adaptivecards.io/content/cats/1.png"
       }
    ],
    "version":"1.0",
    "actions":[ 
       { 
          "type":"Action.OpenUrl",
          "title":"Open Link",
          "url":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/xxxxx?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.com%0A&height=large&width=large&title=Wikipedia-Embed"
       }
    ]
 }
```

And, please confirm if you have the latest version of Teams app?

Comment: I am using 'AdaptiveCard' only. One thing to confirm, this is an outlook targeted adaptive card..